# Showing Error in a php function

Tags: php, function

I have declared a function called test_input in my php script,which working absolutely fine in another scripts.

It shows error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test_input() in C:\xampp\htdocs\submitdata\cwisubmit.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\submitdata\cwisubmit.php on line 25

My php script is:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

echo "Database Connected SUCCESSFULLY";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    // Variables initialization
    $fname=$lname=$dob=$phone=$email=$postcode=$staddress=$city=$lan=$lcwi=$ptype=$mhtype="";

    // Retrieving the data from the form
    $fname=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['fname']));
    $lname=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lname']));
    $dob=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['dob']));
    $phone=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phone']));
    $email=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']));
    $postcode=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['postcode']));
    $staddress=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['staddress']));
    $city=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['city']));
    $lan=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lan']));
    $lcwi=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lcwi']));
    $ptype=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ptype']));
    $mhtype=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mhtype']));

  function test_input($data) {
      $data=trim($data);
      $data=stripslashes($data);
      return $data;
  }

  //sql insert
  $sql="INSERT INTO cwi(fname, lname, dob, phone, email, postcode, staddress, city, lan, lcwi, ptype, mhtype) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$dob','$phone','$email','$postcode','$staddress','$city','$lan','$lcwi','$ptype','$mhtype')";

  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
      echo "<center>RECORDS UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY</center>";
  }else{
      echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
  }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Please check this code whether there is error in my code or why its returning this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP functions can be called before defining it because PHP parses the file first and then executes it. But here is the twist.

> Functions that are enclosed in a conditional statement(if else) will
>   not be parsed. It will be only available after PHP interprets `if`

So, You have to move your function outside of `IF` block like

```
if(condition){
//your code
}
//Your function
  function test_input($data){
      $data=trim($data);
      $data=stripslashes($data);
      return $data;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes are made to the code try this. It should work fine.

```
<?php 


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
   {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 



echo "Database Connected SUCCESSFULLY";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
  //Variables initaition
  $fname=$lname=$dob=$phone=$email=$postcode=$staddress=$city=$lan=$lcwi=$ptype=$mhtype="";

  //Retrieving the data from the form
  $fname=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['fname']));
  $lname=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lname']));
  $dob=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['dob']));
  $phone=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phone']));
  $email=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']));
  $postcode=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['postcode']));
  $staddress=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['staddress']));
  $city=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['city']));
  $lan=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lan']));
  $lcwi=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lcwi']));
  $ptype=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ptype']));
  $mhtype=test_input(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mhtype']));


  //sql insert
  $sql="INSERT INTO cwi(fname, lname, dob, phone, email, postcode, staddress, city, lan, lcwi, ptype, mhtype) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$dob','$phone','$email','$postcode','$staddress','$city','$lan','$lcwi','$ptype','$mhtype')";

  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
      echo "<center>RECORDS UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY</center>";
  }else{
      echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
  }
        }

  $conn->close();

  function test_input($data)
 {
      $data=trim($data);
      $data=stripslashes($data);
      return $data;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

define your test_input() function outside of

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
```

and your code

```
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
```

seems miss "}"